# SimplePanel not being displayed

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

I have the following code used to create a FlowPanel and a couple of SimplePanels to it :

```
    panel = new FlowPanel();
    panel.setStylePrimaryName(MSTYLE);

    sPanel1 = new SimplePanel();
    sPanel.setStyleName(BSTYLE);

    RowLabel = new Label();

    sPanel2 = new SimplePanel();
    sPanel2.setStyleName(BSTYLE);

    panel.add(sPanel1);
    panel.add(RowLabel);
    panel.add(sPanel2);
```

However when I view the page in Browser I am unable to see the simple panels - just the label appears.Am I missing something else ? Thanks.

Comment: can you create **JSFiddle** or something?

Comment: Hi, I don't think so. This is using the GWT library to create the Panels.

Comment: viola.colinalworth.com is a fiddle for GWT - still in progress, and not using the latest RC yet, but it should work for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your SimplePanel's are 0px width and 0px heigh since they don't contain anything.

Try to add a label to the simplepanels and see if those display.
After this try to give the SimplePanel's a width and height (sPanel1.setSize(width, height)).

Comment: Yes, you were exactly right ! After I had corrected the styling in the associated CSS file it displayed correctly